# Iterating over seemingly identical dask arrays takes different time

Tags: python, dask

I'm trying to read a mixture of files (npy, csv, etc) of unknown sizes using Dask. The files will be converted to arrays and merged into one before undergoing some operations that involve slicing.

However, I'm noticing significant speed differences depending on how the arrays are created. Consider the following two methods of creating an array from a csv:

- using numpy.readtxt and dask.array.from_array,
- using dask.dataframe.read_csv and dask.dataframe.to_dask_array.

Now, simply iterating over the first array is nearly a 1000 times faster than iterating over the second one. I am going to assume that this is because the array was created using an object already in memory.

To my understanding, the first array consists of a single chunk and therefore iterating over it is relatively fast. **However, even if I rechunk the second array to match the first one, the iteration speed does not increase significantly.** I also notice that the array.nbytes property shows the same number for both arrays, which suggests to me that they are both fully present in memory.

My expectation was that once I start iterating over the array, Dask would read the relevant chunks necessary into memory. And since there is only one chunk that fits in memory (for this particular case), I'd expect the speeds to be comparable, disregarding the overhead of reading the chunk into memory a single time. Please help me understand what mistake I'm making in my reasoning here.

Below is a minimal example that demonstrates this behavior [python 3.6.2, numpy 1.17.4, dask 2.9.0]:

```
import time                                                                                          
import numpy as np                                                                                   
import dask.array as da                                                                              
import dask.dataframe as dd                                                                          

def make_files():                                                                                    
    np.random.random(0)                                                                              
    mat = np.random.random((6000, 784))                                                                
    np.savetxt('data.csv', mat, delimiter=',', header=','.join(str(x) for x in range(784)))          

def from_csv_via_np():                                                                               
    mat = np.loadtxt('data.csv', delimiter=',', skiprows=1)                                          
    arr = da.from_array(mat)                                                                         
    return arr                                                                                       

def from_csv_via_df():                                                                               
    df = dd.read_csv('data.csv')                                                                     
    arr = df.to_dask_array(lengths=True)                                                             
    arr = da.rechunk(arr, (6000, 784))                                                               
    return arr                                                                                       

def benchmark(fn):                                                                                   
    arr = fn()                                                                                       

    iter_start = time.perf_counter()                                                                 
    n_iters = 10                                                                                     
    for i in range(n_iters):                                                                         
        x = arr[i].compute()                                                                         

    iter_elapsed = (time.perf_counter() - iter_start)/n_iters                                        

    print(f"func: {fn.__name__}")                                                                    
    print(f"    array: {repr(arr)}")                                                                 
    print(f"    read: {read_elapsed} seconds")                                                       
    print(f"    iter: {iter_elapsed} seconds")                                                       
    print(f"    size: {arr.nbytes} bytes")                                                           

if __name__ == "__main__":                                                                           
    make_files()                                                                                     
    benchmark(from_csv_via_np)                                                                       
    benchmark(from_csv_via_df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I've figured out the answer on my own after reading the [Dask internals](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-design.html#keys-of-the-dask-graph) documentation more carefully.

The arrays are **not** identical internally, and I realized after looking at the underlying [task graphs](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/spec.html). They can be plotted with the following command:

```
arr.visualize('image.pdf')
```

[Here is the graph of a numpy backed array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwpOh.png) and [here is the graph of a dataframe backed array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Guk13.png), both accessing the first element of the arrays.

As you can see, the first one is fairly simple and it originates at a single chunk, which turns out to be the original numpy array itself, stored in memory. That can also be verified by printing the graph dictionary, accessible at:

```
arr.__dask_graph__().layers
```

In contrast, the second graph is relatively complex, and it originates at two different read_csv tasks. And since Dask, by default, [does not retain intermediate results](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/caching.html) it is safe to assume that these computations happen for each call to .compute(). For some cases, [caching](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/caching.html) may help resolving similar issues.

So the short answer is, the array originating at the dataframe requires repeated I/O calls, which makes it much slower than the numpy one which reads directly from RAM.